# Null pointer exception when executing loop in clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(defn my-loop [x] 
            (cond (> x 1)
                  ((println x)
                  (my-loop (- x 1)))
            ) 
    )

;; => #'user/my-loop
user> (my-loop 10)
```

Why do i get a null pointer exception, when executing this function?
Is this not a normal recursion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are invoking the return of `(println x)` with the additional layer of parentheses. `println` returns `nil` so invoking it will lead to the `NullPointerException`.

To evaluate more than one form where only one is expected use the `do` special form, which evaluates any number of forms and returns the value of the last one:

```
(defn my-loop [x]
  (cond (> x 1) (do
                  (println x)
                  (my-loop (- x 1)))))
```

In this case, `when` can replace a one armed `cond` and `do`

```
(defn my-loop [x]
  (when (> x 1)
    (println x)
    (my-loop (- x 1))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The code should typically look something like so:

```
(defn my-loop 
  "Some docstring"
  [x] 
  (cond 
    (> x 1)  (println x)
    :else    (my-loop (- x 1))))
```

Keeping to good formatting helps to see problems early.
You may also be interested in this [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet & the book "Getting Clojure".

Comment: "Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/cond at ... cond requires an even number of forms"

Comment: Did it too fast!  Updated answer. It runs, but is not doing the recursion right.